# verify if column values in excel are sorted

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with a column which has sorted values ex.numbers,names.
I want to verify using Vb script whether the values are sorted instead of checking it manually. So is there any code or method or functions in vbscript which verifies the above.

Please help me .....
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through all values and check if they are sorted:

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 2
Dim oldValue as Integer
oldValue = MySheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
Dim sorted as Boolean
sorted = True
Do While Not IsEmpty(MySheet.Cells(i, 1)) And sorted
  If MySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value < oldValue Then
    sorted = False
  EndIf
  oldValue = MySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Evaluate to replicate a formula that checks each value against the one below it.  You'd have to build a check for the cell that's just beyond the range you want to check.  This only checks the first column of the range provided.

```
Function IsRangeSorted(rRng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim lResult As Long

    'If the cell just beyond the range is sorted, evaluate will return zero
    'If not, evaluate returns 1 but we don't care if that cell is sorted
    If rRng.Cells(rRng.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value >= rRng.Cells(rRng.Rows.Count, 1).Value Then
        lResult = 0
    Else
        lResult = 1
    End If

    IsRangeSorted = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & rRng.Columns(1).Address & ">=" & rRng.Columns(1).Offset(1).Address & "))") = lResult

End Function
```